# @font-face Font doesn't render in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some fonts that are used throughout my site and in IE the font doesn't render correctly (at all). I've done some researching around and it appears I need to set it to installable embedding allowed. I've tried using http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/ but when I download the embed.exe the terminal doesn't appear. This is only an Issue in IE works fine in chrome, opera, safari and firefox.

IE Console Log:

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid-sans-regular';
    src: url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need the eot font type for ie:

```
  src: url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 and above */
  src: url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE8 */
```